# Point of interesection between ln and exponential functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\ln(x) = 1 - 1.2^x$

Looking at the functions graphically the solution is ≈ 0.85.

Is there a way to algebraically determine the precise point of intersection?

I can isolate one "x" or the other, but not both:

$\ln(x) = 1 - 1.2^x$

$x = e^{1 - 1.2^x}$

or

$1 - 1.2^x = \ln(x)$

$-1.2^x = \ln(x) - 1$

$1.2^x = -(\ln(x) - 1)$

$1.2^x = (-\ln(x) + 1)$

$x = \log((-\ln(x) + 1))/\log(1.2)$

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we can not express the solution of all  equations with usual fonctions. And you know that already: for example, $$x^2=2$$ do not have solution in $\mathbb Q$, so we have to add a symbol to {integers,*,/,+,-} in order to manipulate the solutions of $x^2=2$ (namely, we add $\sqrt{\cdot}$).

We have the same kind of issue with your equation, you can feel it with all your unsuccesfull try of solving it (we can prove that the solutions of this equation can't be expressed with usual functions but it's a bit tricky) . What we can do:

- study the function $f:x\mapsto \ln(x)-1+1.2^x$ in order to show that $f$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb R^+$, $\lim_{x\to 0} = - \infty$, and $\lim_{x\to +\infty}=+\infty$.
- Hence by the Intermediate value theorem, $f$ is bijective from $\mathbb R^{+*}$  to $\mathbb R$, so $f$ has an inverse $f^{-1}$.

Now, the solution of your equation is $f^{-1}(0)$. We've added the symbol "$f^{-1}$" to our usual langage in order to express this solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Sebastien's answer hints at, there is no way to solve your equation with the usual functions. You need to use a numerical method, like Newton's, to approximate the result.